# SceneKit – Unable to make 3D objects static shape

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit, physics

I already posted my question here but I not got any satisfactory answer, may be question was not clear therefore I'm again posting my problem.

1. I make a 3D tunnel in blender and imported it into sceneKit project
2. In my scene I put a player character which run in this tunnel and its fine.the player runs with camera with user touch as in temple run game.

   ```
   playerNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
   ```
3. When player runs it come cross the tunnel because tunnel is a soft body shape geometry and there is no physics applied
4. I make the physics body type static giving the physics body shape as convex hull but it not work, I also check to make it concave body but problem is same the player come across the walls of tunnel. Here is my code

   ```
   scene = SCNScene(named: "game.scnassets/UpdatedTunnel/second.dae")!
   let Tunnel = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("SketchUp", recursively: true)!
   TunnelNode.addChildNode(Tunnel)
   var shape:SCNPhysicsShape?

   if let geometry = TunnelNode.geometry {
       shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: geometry, options: [SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey: SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConvexHull])
       var nodePhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: shape)
       TunnelNode.physicsBody = nodePhysicsBody
   }
   ```
5. I try different shape types to make the body solid but nothing work for me, I thought maybe something wrong with my 3D .dae tunnel so for check I create a plane in my scene and make it static body type but it also giving the same error my player cross this plane too.

   ```
   let plane = SCNPlane(width:20.0,height:15.0)
   var planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
   planeNode.position = SCNVector3(4.0,0.0,-5.0)
   planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()

   planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static,
                                         shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: plane, options: nil))
   ```

I am badly stuck at this point from many days please someone help me where is my mistake in code and how I can make my tunnel walls solid so the player when hit the walls it should bounce back.
Here is the image in this link you can see [This is my tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckpuN.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide an image of your tunnel geometry? It’s a little unclear from the description what kind of shape it is.

Comment: – Noah Witherspoon i updated my post with tunnel image you can check it...